# jQuery - How do I find an element with partial ID under a specific element

Tags: jquery

I have multiple records, each with the same fields, they all have the same name/id, plus the RecordID.  When I press cmdUpdate_xxx I detect which record div, assigning it to 'fldTarget'.  I know want to check each field (20, so don't want to do this manually) for validity.  I've tried

```
$('#RecordsWrapper')
    .on("click" , "[id*=cmdUpdate]", "input", function(e){
      fldTarget = $(this);
      fldAccountID = fldTarget.parent().find("#txtAccountID").prop("id");`
    })
```

...but fldAccountID comes back as `undefined`.  How can I locate a sub element with an ID that contains 'txtAccountID' under 'Record001' div?

```
<div id='RecordsWrapper'>
<div id='Record001'>
  <input type='text' id='txtAccount_001'>
  <input type='text' id='txtEntry_001'>
  <input type='text' id='txtValue_001'>
  <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_001'>
</div>
<div id='Record002'>
  <input type='text' id='txtAccount_002'>
  <input type='text' id='txtEntry_002'>
  <input type='text' id='txtValue_002'>
  <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_002'>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use attribute selector:

> ## Attribute selectors
>
> Attribute selectors select an element using the presence of a given attribute or attribute value.
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors
>
> REF (more example here): https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

```js
$('input[id^=txtEntry]').css('background', 'green');


$('#RecordsWrapper')
  .on("click", "input[id^=cmdUpdate]", "input", function(e) {
    fldTarget = $(this);
    fldAccountID = fldTarget.parent().find("input[id^=txtAccount]").prop("id");
    console.log('fldAccountID-->' + fldAccountID);
  })
```

```css
input[id^=txtAccount] {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='RecordsWrapper'>
  <div id='Record001'>
    <input type='text' id='txtAccount_001'>
    <input type='text' id='txtEntry_001'>
    <input type='text' id='txtValue_001'>
    <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_001'>
  </div>
  <div id='Record002'>
    <input type='text' id='txtAccount_002'>
    <input type='text' id='txtEntry_002'>
    <input type='text' id='txtValue_002'>
    <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_002'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fldAccountID = fldTarget.parent().find("id^=txtAccount").prop("id"); doesn't work, an alert() I placed after the line is never reached, so it's cutting out on this line?!?!

Comment: @aSystemOverload `fldTarget` what is this one? `id='Record001'`?

Comment: ok, I jumped the gun, saw your update.  I've now changed it to // fldAccountID = fldTarget.parent().find("input[id^=txtAccount]").prop("id"); //  It seems valid, but fldAccountID still appears as 'undefined'

Comment: Just added clarification around fldTarget, Record00x are just div wrappers for each record

Comment: @aSystemOverload ok working now, check the updated one =D

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the div for the current record stored in `fldTarget` can you parse the record ID from that div's own ID?

For example.

```
var recordID = fldTarget.prop('id').replace('Record', '');
var txtAccountID = 'txtAccount_' + recordID;
```

---

Or you could add a `data-*` attribute for each "record" div to hold contain the ID num like this:

```
<div id='Record001' data-id="001">
    <input type='text' id='txtAccount_001'>
    <input type='text' id='txtEntry_001'>
    <input type='text' id='txtValue_001'>
    <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_001'>
</div>
<div id='Record002' data-id="002">
    <input type='text' id='txtAccount_002'>
    <input type='text' id='txtEntry_002'>
    <input type='text' id='txtValue_002'>
    <input type='submit' id='cmdUpdate_002'>
</div>
```

And get the value from that attribute like this:

```
var recordID = fldTarget.data('id');
var txtAccountID = 'txtAccount_' + recordID;
```